laravel passport and react native doesnt work on localhost
i'm working multi-tenant architecture with laravel passport ant tenancyforlaravel package.I trying to create mobile app with react native(using expo). laravel passport works only tenants.
tenant1.localhost:8000 
tenant2.localhost:8000

i request post tenant1.localhost:8000/oauth/token to route. it works well postman or another curl request.
But when i post request in react i give this "LOG  Error: Network request failed"
I think this error reason is app post request post own localhost server.When i change localhost url  (ipv4 ip) for 192.162.3.1:8000 this time post request going to landlord.
Any thoughts for a solution ?
 const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://tenant1.localhost:8000/oauth/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          client_id: 'clientID', // 
          client_secret: 'clientSecret', // 
          grant_type: 'password',
          username: email,
          password: password,
        }),
      });
  
      const responseText = await response.text();
      console.log('Raw Response:', responseText);
  
      const data = JSON.parse(responseText);
      if (response.ok) {
        Alert.alert('Login Successful', `Welcome ${data.fact}`);
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Login Failed', 'Unknown error occurred');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const errorMessage = error.message || JSON.stringify(error);
      console.log('Error:', errorMessage);
      Alert.alert('Error', errorMessage);
    }
  };


If you're using the free plan of Ngrok, it's not an ideal solution because every time you start the Ngrok server, it provides a new URL. You would need to change the tenant domain name in your database for each new Ngrok session

How did you solve it with ngrok? Can you [edit] your answer to provide more detail?
